# duplicate entry: com/mikepenz/google_material_typeface_library/GoogleMaterial$Icon.class

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Getting error in android studio for gradle file. I used mikepenz library file but it get error as follows

```
 com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/mikepenz/google_material_typeface_library/GoogleMaterial$Icon.class
```

bellow is my gradle file in which I used mikepenz library for icons

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
      List<String> dirs = [
         'main',   
        'common',   
        'template'] 

  android {
   compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.demo"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    jumboMode = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

  //Autocomplete address
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
// icon fonts used inside the sample
// https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics
compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics:1.6.2@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:1.6.2@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:octicons-typeface:3.0.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.mikepenz:entypo-typeface:1.0.0.1@aar'

compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.2'
// used to showcase how to load images
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
```

please help me to resolve this problem,

Thanks in advance..

Comment: 'File->Invalidate caches/Restart', after restart 'Build --> Clean' and `Build --> Rebuild prohject` should does the thing. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you include the `iconics`, `iconics-core` and `google-material-typeface` in your project. The `iconics` dependency includes the same class `GoogleMaterial` as the `google-material-typeface` does and so those two classes will conflict. You need to remove one of those two, to get it compiling

You might also want to consider to update to the latest version of the [Android-Iconics](https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics) library.

https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics#1-provide-the-gradle-dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.10@aar'
}
```

Comment: I'm a little late to the conversation, but I seem to be getting a similar error:-   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/mikepenz/iconics/context/IconicsContextWrapper.class

Comment: @Rohan which other dependencies do you have. Looks like you use more of my libs in different versions

Comment: I've added only 2 of them:- compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.1@aar'
and compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.6.0.3@aar

Comment: Ok just those two. And you do not have any other libraries from me?

Comment: no.. none other from you. this started happening after i upgraded to API 24, and had to enable multidex

Comment: Did you do a clean build already? I also use multidex and have no problems ://

Comment: i created an entirely new project and it now works fine!! wonder what went wrong with it.. i did a clean build, deleted caches... everything, but it still didn't work until i decided to give it a fresh start.... But thanks a bunch for the awesome lib Mike :)

Comment: Sorry for the issues you had. Thank you